# Superiority of the Indo-European hypothesis

Tags: comparative-linguistics, indo-european, comparative-method

I am assuming that the hypothesis of an Indo-European phylogenetic relationship is the best of such kind, within the historical-comparative linguistics. It is the best proven, it has the richest data from a huge collection of languages; nobody ever questions its validity as a whole.

It is exemplary and prototypical both in research and teaching. For example, when a new genetic hypothesis is proposed by someone, the IE hypothesis is often used as a reference for evaluating the quality and the quantity of the new hypothesis. Or, again, when students are taught the basics of the comparative method, the IE examples are always the easiest to quote and also the most convincing.

Partly, this is certainly explainable with some random historical conditions: we are extremely lucky in having thousands of years of written attestations of the IE languages.

What I am asking is this: do you feel like there are also some strictly linguistic reasons for the superiority of the IE hypothesis? E.g., some typological property shared by all the oldest IE languages such that the comparison is made easier, the cognate sets are richer, the phonological correspondences are more regular.

This is a serious question, not a curiosity.

Comment: If you have a reference to point to, instead of a questionable phrase "the Indo-European genetic hypothesis", we might be able to answer. Indo-European languages have nothing to do with genetics, except as a metaphor. Are you referring to the metaphor, or to real genetics? If this is a serious question, it needs grounding.

Comment: @jlawler Perhaps I have used the wrong term. I don't mean any genetics, just the genealogical relationship between languages:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_relationship_(linguistics)
How would you call it otherwise?

Comment: I have made an edit to clarify to clarify that the question is not about the genetics of speakers, but about the phylogenetic relationship of the IE languages

Comment: Indo-European has been by far the best- and most thoroughly studied language family for two and a half centuries. That's a lead that's hard to beat. The examples are there and they've been thoroughly worked out. Why not use them?

Comment: @jlawler I am asking whether there is some specifically linguistic reason for this languages to make the biggest success story in historical linguistics. Apart the historical conditions.

Comment: it's also pretty diverse. There aren't many families with analytic, agglutinative, & synthetic members (e.g. english, armenian, & russian), or with as big a range of phonologies (e.g. Danish with 20 vowels, and Greek with 5). Between this and the headstart it has in study, for almost any concept in historical linguistics, there's a known and understood example in Indo-European

Comment: @ArtemijKeidan the head start is probably the largest factor. Historical linguistics essentially developed out of the West's exposure to Sanskrit, and the recognition of its similarities with Latin and Ancient Greek

Comment: Austronesian begins to match that, and may in the future given more study. The story in historical linguistics that continues to astound me is the etiology of New Guinea and Australian languages -- an island with an order of magnitude (or two) more linguistic diversity than the much larger continent it's close to, which is almost all one language family. And both have been settled for over 40,000 years. What's going on?

Comment: @Tristan your first comment is sort of what I meant. If I understand you correctly, your claim is that typological diversity is a major factor for the success of the IE hypothesis.

Comment: success as a teaching aid. The success of it as a theory is on its well-foundedness, which is generally harder to demonstrate with more typologically distant languages. For the other side of this coin see the Semitic languages, which despite having split up before PIE did, have such strong typological similarities that their relatedness has never really been in question, even if the correspondences are so rife with unexplained anomalies that the actual reconstructed lexicon is absolutely tiny

Comment: The question would be clearer if you were more specific about what you are asking (and assuming). What would you put in the blank in the statement "Indo-European is the best illustration of the hypothesis that ___"?

Comment: @user6726 "Indo-European is the best illustration of the fact that genealogically related languages share a large number of cognate roots correlated phoneme-by-phoneme through a set of regular correspondences".

Answer (score 3):

IMO the reasons why Proto-Indo-European is one of the best studied languages are: 1) a lot of work has been done on this issue, which is not the case for many linguistic families in the world, 2) we have a lot of well-described data on many IEan languages, which makes serious work possible, 3) Old Indian served as a reference at the beginning of IEan studies, which made things easier, as people never had to look for a proto-system, Old Indian gave it on a golden plate.
That being said, not everything in PIE as it is now reconstructed is satisfactory.
One could also add that PIE is not extremely ancient, which obviously makes work easier than with very ancient families like Afrasian.

Comment: What do you mean by Old Indian? How did it serve as a reference?

Comment: Old Indian is Indo-Aryan, the subbranch of Indo-Iranian spoken in NW India. Originally, in the early 1800s people thought Old Indian was representative of PIE, for that matter, the phonological system of Old Indian served as basis for PIE. This was gradually criticized and abandoned in the 1850s.

Comment: Does the term include classical Sanskrit? The older Prakrits?

Comment: Sanskrit is an artificial hypernormative language, based on Old Indian. What is "classical" (??) Sanskrit?

Comment: I believe it's what you refer to as hypernormative. The standardised form of Sanskrit, as given by the Grammars of Panini. Opposed to Vedic Sanskrit, an even older form.

Comment: In the anglophone tradition it is usually known as Old Ind*ic*, not Ind*ian*. Classical Sanskrit is a fairly common term, see e.g. Forston 2010: 209-ff. I’ll try to see what Louis Renou wrote on this some time later.

Answer (score 3):

May I play the devil's advocate and make the claim that the Indogermanic language family isn't superior as an example of a well-defined language family. It is just the most convenient example for a majority of active linguists who are speaking at least one (often more) Indogermanic language, often as a native language, and many of them had contact to a classical language such as Latin or Sanskrit early on in their lives. This makes it easier to track an argument or an etymology, and the examples are often already familiar.

Historically, Finno-Ugric was established as a language family even before Indogermanic, and in its current shape (Uralic) it is an excellent source of examples. Also, the Austronesian language family, as mentioned before, is a very well established family, rich in members, rich in typological variation, and provides good material. And, I think the Semitic branch of Afro-Asiatic also provides excellent time depth, lots of material and many languages, with the bonus of established external relationships to a larger language family.

Comment: I'm surprised at how early the relatedness of Hungarian to Finno-Samic was recognised (the languages of what's now Russia not being documented at that stage were obviously largely absent). Thanks for bringing that to my attention

Comment: I will say that Semitic is a really terrible choice of case study though. Despite having a similar (albeit slightly greater) time depth than PIE, the lexicon is patchy at best, there are major open morphological questions, and phonological correspondences are so rife with anomalies that distinguishing genuine reflexes from borrowings is frequently impossible. Expanding to Afro-Asiatic those problems multiply

Comment: I took a year of non-Indo-European historical in grad school, and the non-I-E family that year was Uralic, with a Finnish native speaker as professor. Very interesting. Vowol harmonu everywhere.

Comment: Except not *that* kind of harmony.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to take a stab an a devil's advocate answer that focuses on the *linguistic* reasons, though I believe the non-linguistic reasons are the actual explanation for the educational success of IE. It's *really hard* to set aside the non-linguistic factors.

The main factor, IMO, is the diversity of sound changes within IE. The distance, measured in sound changes, from PIE to the major first- or second-order groups of daughter languages is quite substantial, at least in some respects. As an exercise in appreciating the power of the comparative method, how in the world did they figure out *gʷ and *gʷʰ. How many language actually attest *{m̩ n̩ r̩ l̩}? Of course, the 1-to-myriad mapping of PIE sounds vs. the 1-to-many mappings of Finno-Ugric is not enough, one shold also consider the 1-to-myriad mappings of Bantu: but who know anything about Bantu? (a non-linguistic factor).

I can't offer much more, because the reasons are in fact non-linguistic, they are sociological.

Comment: Interesting point of view.